# why does this code lock my files?

Tags: c#, .net, file, locking, wallpaper

Ive narrowed down to this method but i don't understand why its locking the file. I believe you could use something like

```
using( something)
{

//do stuff here
}
```

But im not sure that would A) solve the issue or B) be the correct way if it did.

any ideas?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 action, UInt32 uParam, String vParam, UInt32 winIni);  
    private static readonly UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER  = 0x14;  
    private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE    = 0x01;  
    private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;  

    private void SetWallpaper(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            Image imgInFile = Image.FromFile(path);
            imgInFile.Save(SaveFile, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 3, SaveFile, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error in setting the wallpaper");
        }
    }
```

#

Updated code

```
 private void SetWallpaper(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Image imgInFile = Image.FromFile(path);
            try
            {
                imgInFile.Save(SaveFile, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 3, SaveFile, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error in setting the wallpaper");
            }
            finally
            {
                imgInFile.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx): "The file remains locked until the Image is disposed." - so yes, this should be fixed by:

```
using (Image imgInFile ...) { ... }
```

(As a side note, I would tighten the try catch to just the .Save() and/or SystemParametersInfo() calls)

Comment: I'd also throw in : if(File.exists(path)) { .. }

Comment: @Nippysaurus: I would like SetWallpaper() to throw, myself.

Comment: i guess my question is how is that different than when the method is finished running. shouldn't the image be automatically disposed of after it completes?

Comment: No. It is automaticly disposed when it is garbage collected, but that could be anything from a few seconds to never from then (excluding forced collecting, which you should pretty much never do).

Answer (score 1):

Once you pass out of the **using** block, all objects initialized within it are disposed.  In your case, the objects will be disposed which will remove the lock on the file.

You must manually dispose (either through a **using** statement or by calling *.Dispose()* on the object) any unmanaged calls to either COM or Windows API functions (i.e. when you use interop).

Comment: `using` only calls .Dispose() on the expression inside the parens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have please let me know if you see anything that i could pretty up. But its working like a champ so i'm pretty happy.

```
                private void SetWallpaper(string path)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        Image imgInFile = Image.FromFile(path);
                        try
                        {
                            imgInFile.Save(SaveFile, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 3, SaveFile, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("error in setting the wallpaper");
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            imgInFile.Dispose();
                        }
                    }

                    Else
                    {
                          messagebox.show("Error with path: "+path+" Not found or in use");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This should behave the same as `if (File.Exists(path)) using(Image imgInFile = Image.FromFile(path)) try {...} catch {...}` (no finally). But thats just style.