# Detect multiple monitors and set separate wallpapers for each

Tags: c#, windows, wallpaper

I'm starting a project to make a wall paper rotator for computers with multiple monitors.

1) how do you detect the monitors in windows and the associated resolution

2) how would i set the image per monitor. do I make one image that's crafted together or do I set each one individually and how?

thanks

Comment: This all depends on the client used to run the app ... Citrix takes your dual (or more) monitors and turns it into one huge one.

Comment: Can someone please edit the title to correct the spelling.  Pretty-please.  :)

Comment: oops on the title. @ martin you probably wouldn't change the background on a citrix environment anyway

Answer (score 1):

1. You can get information about all screens using the `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` class. Use their bounds properties to determine their layout.
2. Not possible on Windows (XP), you'll have to craft a big background image using the drawing routines in System.Drawing.

This "thread" contains some more info on manipulating wallpapers in windows: [why does this code lock my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805041/why-does-this-code-lock-my-files)